# How to load particular data from HDFS to HIVE

Tags: hive, hdfs

I have a file named patient in the form of text which has data in following format in HDFS

```
e93f4078|8e09-4699|Patient|2018-04-30 10:02:46.766078|2018-04-28 06:20:38.435445|null|{"id": "8e09-4699", "meta": {"versionId": "e93f4078-f01e2a4e}}|null
315b0f5f|442a-a6d2|Patient|2018-04-30 11:18:20.725076|2018-04-30 09:42:05.603234|null|{"id": "442a-a6d2", "meta": {"versionId": "315b0f5f-6105"}} |null
```

I want to load the particular column having json into Hive table having column names as id and meta. Can anyone suggest idea to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two phases.

1. Load this dataset from csv as is in raw table with all those separate columns (pipe separated). You should have one column with json text.
2. Select json column from raw table and populate your data table with two columns id and meta.

Comment: how do i check the versionId to a particular string? I did like: select * from patient where get_json_object(meta,'$.versionId')like 'e93f4078-f01e2a4e' but its not working accordingly.

Comment: I think you should do smth like `get_json_object(col_with_json, '$.meta.versionId')`

Comment: basically you need provide full path to the element, but not just the latest name.

Comment: yeah i tried the same too. but in vain.   select * from patient where get_json_object(meta,'$.meta.versionId') is not null;select * from patient where get_json_object(meta,'$.meta.versionId') is null; these both queries are working but not the one I want to.

Comment: Your JSON above is invalid. Every open quote must have a closed one. Works perfectly for me:  `select get_json_object('{"id": "8e09-4699", "meta": {"versionId": "e93f4078-f01e2a4e"}}', '$.meta.versionId');`

Answer (score 1):

Use **Regex serde** and capture only the **id and meta values** in the text file.

Try with below hive.ddl:

```
hive> CREATE TABLE details(
  id STRING,
  meta string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES  (
"input.regex" = "^.+:\\s\"(.*?)\",\\s\"meta\":\\s+(.*)}.+$"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Select from hive table:

```
hive> select * from details;
+------------+------------------------------------+--+
|     id     |                meta                |
+------------+------------------------------------+--+
| 8e09-4699  | {"versionId": "e93f4078-f01e2a4e}  |
| 442a-a6d2  | {"versionId": "315b0f5f-6105"}     |
+------------+------------------------------------+--+
```

change the regex in hive.ddl as per your requirements.

**(or)**

another way is to create temp hive table **with | delimited** then by using **get_json_object.**.etc functions you can extract only the required data from the **temp hive table** and then **insert into New target table**.